# Is it ordinary that near-field probes do not detect EM noise?

Tags: noise, emc, spectrum-analyzer

Last week we did a pre-certification test with a device and it failed.

Description of the device:

- It is powered from Li-ion battery. It integrates a BQ24090DGQT which is a Li-ion battery charger, the charging current comes from an external charger that we connect to a micro-USB port (like a smartphone)
- It has a MCU which drives high-current LEDs and low-current LEDs, and a DC motor.

The horizontal and vertical curves of the test were quite good when the device is on battery
[image]

When we connected the charger to the micro-USB connector, the vertical curves showed noise at 30 MHz and 50 MHz:
[image]

We did some tests and we had the following conclusions:

- The problem does not come from a specific device (another one had the same curves).
- The problem does not come from powering the LEDs and the motor because we simply had the device connected to the charger without launching the firmware.
- We managed to suppress the noise at 30 MHz by rolling up aluminium foil around the charger and the USB cable, still the noise at 50 MHz remained

I am using a spectrum analyzer (SSA3032X from Siglent) with near-field probes and I thought I would be able to find the same noise at 50 MHz but after inspecting all over the device, nothing! Here are the specs of the probe I am using :

[image]

And here is my setup :

[image]
So I have three questions:

- Is it normal that these noises at 40 dBm are not detected by the near-field probes?
- I have very little experience with EMC curves. By looking at the curves, do you have ideas on what could be the cause of this?
- If I cannot detect the noise with the near-field probes, is there a way to check it without passing EMC tests?

Thanks!

Comment: Near-field probes should pick that up.

Comment: Check which frequency span your probe is specified for? Mine say >1MHz. We can't really answer without knowing what probe you are using.

Comment: Do you know what's happening below 30 MHz?

Comment: A picture or cartoon of your setup would help.  Is the USB charger in the same room/enclosure as your DUT (device under test)?

Comment: I have added two pictures : specs of the probe and setup configuration. The probe should detect signals at 50 MHz. I do not know what was happenning below 30 MHz when I did the pre-certification tests.
Yes the USB charger was in the same room as my DUT. If I inspect the cable and the charger with the near-field probe, it does not detect anything... But I know that the probe IS working because it detects spikes on the device of another project.

Comment: Do we get the same measuring result whether the DUT is powered or not? Or without DUT?

Comment: https://www.lowemfoffice.com/usb_cables.htm ?

Comment: When USB is connected, the curves are the same whether the main firmware of the DUT is launched or not. If I plug the USB, the DUT is automatically powered but a button must be pressed to launch the firmware. During the EMC tests I have not tried testing only the charger because I thought that in such a case no current would be drawn from the charger, so it would not really act the same as if there was the DUT. But during the test we have isolated the charger and its cable (aluminium foil all round + putting it away from the measuring table)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are measuring the noise of the external charger, not your equipment; you'd be better off using a USB battery pack as your supply, since it won't contribute any extra noise to the tests.

With regard to near-field measurements, we used a few turns of wire wound into a small coil, and soldered it to an SMA connector; it made a very good search coil for finding interference similar to yours.

You can probably find calculations on the correct dimensions for a 50 MHz search coil; we just guessed, and it worked sufficiently well for our purposes.